Json Schema not evaluating if else condition properly in draft version 2020-12
I use a json schema which refers to another json schema as follows :
Schema 1 (cache_test.json)
{
        "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
        "$id": "https://json-schema.org/schema/cache_test.json",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "accName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "insData": {
                "$ref": "./test.json"
            },
            "secData": {
                "$ref": "./test.json"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "accName",
            "insData"
        ],
        "definitions": {
            "string_validation": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "string_or_null_validation": {
                "type": ["string", "null"]
            }
        }
    }

Schema 2(test.json) which is referred from schema 1 is defined as follows :
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://json-schema.org/schema/test.json",
    "type": "array",
    "items":
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "referenceval": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/string_validation"
            },
            "tableName": {
                "enum": [
                    "TABLE1",
                    "TABLE2",
                    "TABLE3",
                    "TABLE4",
                    "TABLE5",
                    "TABLE6",
                    "TABLE7",
                    "TABLE8",
                    "TABLE9"
                ]
            },
            "code": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/string_validation"
            },
            "contractType": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/string_validation"
            }
        },
        "allOf": [
            {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "tableName": {
                            "const": "TABLE1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "referenceval"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "tableName": {
                            "const": "TABLE2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "code"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "tableName": {
                            "const": "TABLE3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "contractType"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "definitions": {
        "string_validation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "string_or_null_validation": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
    }
}

The problem is that in Schema 2 (test.json), it does not validate the if-else condition correctly. i.e For example, if tableName is 'TABLE2' in my json input and if the field 'referenceval' is not there in the input, it is complaining that 'referenceval' is required. As per the if-condition, 'referenceval' is required only if tableName is 'TABLE1'. I am using the library 'com.networknt json-schema-validator' and the code that I am using to validate the above json is as below:
public List<String> validateInputDataTest(String jsonInput){
    List<String> validationErrors = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
      InputStream mainSchemaStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema/cache_test.json");
      InputStream subSchemaStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema/test.json");
      ObjectMapper mapperSubSchema = new ObjectMapper();
      JsonNode jsonNodeSubSchema = mapperSubSchema.readValue(subSchemaStream, JsonNode.class);
      String referencedSchema = mapperSubSchema.writeValueAsString(jsonNodeSubSchema);

      JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V202012,
          builder -> builder.schemaLoaders(schemaLoaders -> schemaLoaders.schemas(
              Collections.singletonMap("https://json-schema.org/schema/test.json", referencedSchema))));

      JsonSchema schema = factory.getSchema(mainSchemaStream);

      SchemaValidatorsConfig schemaValidatorsConfig = new SchemaValidatorsConfig();
      schemaValidatorsConfig.setFailFast(false);
      schemaValidatorsConfig.setHandleNullableField(true);

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonInput);
      Set<ValidationMessage> validationMessages = schema.validate(jsonNode);
      for(ValidationMessage validationMessage : validationMessages){
        validationErrors.add(validationMessage.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Validation error:" +  validationMessage.getMessage());
      }
    }catch(Exception e){
      log.error("Error while validating input json");
      validationErrors.add("Error while validating input json");
    }
    return validationErrors;
  }

Please let me know what can be done to validate the if else condition correctly in the above schema?

Can you share some data that's not validating the way you expect it to?  It works as I expect in my validator with [{"tableName": "TABLE2", "code": ""}].

Also, which implementation are you using?  There is a conformance report at https://bowtie.report/#/?language=java, and it shows that they all pass the test suite.

You have indicated that you are using com.networknt.json-schema-validator but testing with https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/json/any/upload which uses it as a upstream component doesn't show any errors with [{"tableName": "TABLE2", "code": ""}] as input if just the test.json schema is used.
I suspect that what is happening is that the input data has omitted or misspelt the tableName property resulting in the errors.
If you are using if with properties you would typically also use required otherwise if the property is omitted it would validate successfully as properties are optional.
